# Scrapy xpath not able to extract

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract data from [link](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=06T-0045-00045), I used

`scrapy shell "https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=06T-0045-00045"`

I got correct response, but can't get the Xpath to work,i.e getting the price with `response.xpath('//li[@class="price-current"]')` returns empty, I tried also `response.xpath('//*[@id="landingpage-price"]/div/div/ul')` but also empty, When I use `response.xpath('//*[@id="landingpage-price"]')` it works but anything deeper returns empty.

Comment: this page uses `JavaScript` to put data in HTML. Scrapy can't run JavaScript. Open web browser, turn off JavaScript and load page to see what scrapy can see. If you can't find your data in this page then you may have to use Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript. Or you have to find out where JavaScript get this data. If data are somewhere in HTML then you can get it. If JavaScript get data from server then you can find this url and use it to get data (mostly as JSON so you can easily convert it to python's dictionary)

Comment: @furas doesn't `view(response)` show me exactly what Scrapy sees?

Comment: there is JavaScript code in HTML in `response` and it runs this HTML in web browser which runs JavaScript so you see more then scrapy can see. Turn off JavaScript in browser and then you will see exactly the same data as scrapy.

Comment: @furas thanks for explanation, to be completely clear `scrapy shell ...` the temporary html scrapy gets doesn't include Javascript. but if i `view(response)` in browser (chrome) chrome will run the scripts hence `view(response)` html will be different than original html right?

Comment: No, scrapy gets HTML with JavaScript. It can be part of HTML in tags `<script>` and/or there are links to load external files with JavaScript. But scrapy can't run JavaScript. Scrapy needs Selenium or similar tool to run JavaScript.

Comment: see [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) and [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to check source HTML (`Ctrl+U`). There is `<meta itemprop='price' content='78.23' />` in the source. So simple:

```
response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content').extract_first()
```

will work.

Comment: it works, but why does the inspection tools give me different path (when in `view(response)`?

Comment: Inspection tools show you rendered HTML (after all scripts update DOM)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same question for the whole day and find this answer perfect for this:

```
response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content').get()
```